# How to install qt5 in Fedora 30

Tags: fedora, qt

I really have no clue about how to install qt5 in Fedora 30.

I need to use paraview which complains about some missing software:

```
$ ./paraview
./paraview: /home/jimmy/Scaricati/ParaView-5.7.0-RC2-MPI-Linux-Python3.7-64bit/bin/../lib/libQt5Core.so.5: version `Qt_5.12' not found (required by /usr/lib64/libQt5Network.so.5)
./paraview: /home/jimmy/Scaricati/ParaView-5.7.0-RC2-MPI-Linux-Python3.7-64bit/bin/../lib/libQt5Core.so.5: version `Qt_5.12.4_PRIVATE_API' not found (required by /usr/lib64/libQt5Network.so.5)
```

I'm using Fedora 30.

I already installed `qt, qt-devel, qt5, qt5-devel` from the distribution repo.
What else should I do?

Comment: I believe you should install qt5-devel with `sudo dnf install qt5-devel`. You may also need `sudo dnf install qt-creator`.

Comment: I've just installed that qt-creator too, but it doesn't solve the missing libraries/software.

Comment: `libQt5Core.so.5` is provided by the package `qt5-qtbase` : `/usr/lib64/libQt5Core.so.5`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was a bad LD_LIBRARY_PATH in my bashrc.
I didn't have to install any additional package, since paraview executable come with all the needed libraries, which were not correctly loaded due to the LD_LIBRARY_PATH variable.

Answer (score 9):

The packages you're missing are **qt5-qtbase** and **qt5-qtbase-devel**.

Comment: I did this and still it doesn't work :(
`
$ sudo dnf install qt qt-devel qt5 qt5-devel qt5-qtbase qt5-qtbase-devel
`

Comment: What does `find /home/jimmy/Scaricati -name libQt5Core.so.5` show? From your command-line above, you might have another version of this file that's the wrong version.

Comment: Your guess is correct!
I had a bad LD_LIBRARY_PATH in my bashrc. I edited that and now paraview works using its own libraries packed in its folders.